# How do I use the WHERE clause to query data between two date ranges? - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use the WHERE clause to call data within a specific date range

My query below, where have I gone wrong?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE daterange
BEGIN

WHERE DATE(A.RaceDate) = (A.RaceDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01'AND '2018-01-01') 

SELECT A.ID,

       A.RaceDate,
       track.Name AS Track,
       A.BFSP,

FROM raceresult A
LEFT OUTER JOIN track ON track.ID = A.TrackID

ORDER BY Track, A.RaceDate ASC
;    
END
```

Comment: The syntax error is because you have an extra comma before `FROM`.

Comment: Your `WHERE` should be after the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and before the `ORDER BY`. Basic tip when building a query. Start small and add one thing each time until you found the error

Comment: But you shouldn't use `DATE(A.RaceDate) =` before the range conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause of your query belongs in the query, not outside/before it.  I suggest the following updated version:

```
WHERE A.RaceDate >= '2017-01-01' AND A.RaceDate < '2018-01-02'
```

Note that I use inequalities here, and the condition on the right says to take the entire date of `2018-01-01` as the last full day to be included.

Your updated query might look like this:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM raceresult A
LEFT JOIN track ON track.ID = A.TrackID
LEFT JOIN going ON going.ID = A.GoingID
LEFT JOIN type ON type.ID = A.TypeID
LEFT JOIN type Type1 ON Type1.ID = A.Type1ID
LEFT JOIN type Type2 ON Type2.ID = A.Type2ID
LEFT JOIN distance ON distance.ID = A.DistanceID
WHERE A.RaceDate >= '2017-01-01' AND A.RaceDate < '2018-01-02'
ORDER BY Track, A.RaceDate, `Time`, BFSP
```

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

1; First issue was the position of WHERE clause, this belongs after the joins and before an ORDER condition

2; There was an additional comma (,) on the last field of the SELECT statement. This comma indicates that another fields is expected.

Changes starred below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE daterange
BEGIN

SELECT A.ID,

       A.RaceDate,
       track.Name AS Track,
       A.BFSP --**

FROM raceresult A
LEFT OUTER JOIN track ON track.ID = A.TrackID
WHERE A.RaceDate >= '2017-01-01' AND A.RaceDate < '2018-01-02' --**
ORDER BY Track, A.RaceDate ASC
;    
END
```